# Plotting a parametric graph and a normal one on the same grid with a legend option

Tags: plotting, legending

Here is my simple code:

```
f0[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y]
f1[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]
ParametricPlot[{{f0[y], f1[y]}, {y, f1[y]}}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, BaseStyle -> 18, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{
        Style["density composite", FontSize -> 21],
        Style["density only", FontSize-> 21]
        }, 
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), 
        BaseStyle -> 18], {Right, Top}]]
```

[image]

I only get the legend "density composite" but not "density only" part. I need them in the same plot. One is for the blue curve and the other for the red one.

Thank you very much

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Öskå version 9 I use.

Comment: According to the documentation `ParametricPlot[{{2 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` works. So it should be working with the example give in the Q&A.

Comment: @Öskå  But I cannot use expressions. I have this: Placed[LineLegend[{Style["Outliers", FontSize -> 21], 
   Style["Modeling errors", FontSize -> 21]}, 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, 
      FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), BaseStyle -> 18], {Right, Top}]

Comment: I can not help you further since I don't have _v9_..

Comment: @Öskå you dont have __v i didnt understand but thanks anyways for the comments. Should I edit the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I pressed enter before finishing, I edited my comment now. And I believe that you should indeed :)

Comment: @Öskå I did it. I think it is much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f0[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y];
f1[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y];
ParametricPlot[{{f0[y], f1[y]}, {y, f1[y]}}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
  PlotStyle ->{Blue, Red}, BaseStyle ->18, AspectRatio -> .7, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"density composite", "density only"}, LabelStyle->21,
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &)],
   {Right, Top}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. I learned something new.

Comment: @Seyhmus, glad it was useful. Thanks for the accept.